# why does texstudio show "\linespread" as an unrecognized command?

Tags: texstudio

besides `\linespread`, the `\center` also is told an unrecognized command. I don't know what's wrong with TeXStudio. Can any one help me?

Comment: Please help us to help by providing a complete code which demonstrates your problem. The information you have provided is rather insufficient.

Comment: Possibly a typographers' conspiration: they want nobody knows about `\linespread` so documents will be better spaced. `;-)` Out of joke: TeXStudio people forgot to add it to their list.

Comment: In addition to what @egreg says, `\center` is a LaTeX environment rather than a command, so while `\center` will work it should be used as `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`. (I'm assuming you are using LaTeX here!)

Comment: @JosephWright what about `\center` ... `\endcenter`?

Comment: @1010011010 Due to the way environment are implemented in LaTeX2e you can put `\foo` ... and perhaps `\endfoo` in place of `\begin{foo}` ... `\end{foo}`, but that does not make it 'supported'. Missing out `\begin` means no group is added, and there is no certainty that `\endfoo` is defined (it's not required for an environment to work).

Answer (score 3):

See the FAQ: [Why does TeXstudio mark a command as unrecognized](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-texstudio-mark-a-command-as-unrecognized)